# How to create a Custom Select List for a netsuite field?

Tags: netsuite

I have a field on a custom record. The name of the field is reference_code.

I want to populate "reference_code" with my own dynamic list which would be presented as a drop down to the user.

How do I do this? I defined my field as Free-Text. Do I need to keep it hidden but then show it as a drop down before I load the form?

I thought this might do something:

```
nlapiInsertSelectOption('custrecord_rulereferencecode', code, code, false)
```

But I would need to convert the field to a select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating two fields. One is created in the RecordType and will store the info. I set this as hidden. The next field, with the custom dropdown is added in user event. I then process data for my custom dynamic select list and add that to my added user event field.

Then in my change event, I set the record type field to the value selected in my dynamically added field.

Userevent

```
function userEventBeforeLoad(type, form, request){
  if(type == "edit"){
    form.addField('custpage_referencecode','select','Reference Code',null, null)
  }  
}
```

In my Client Script:

```
function clientFieldChanged(type, name, linenum){

if(name == 'custpage_referencecode'){
    //obtain the upper case value
    var codetext = nlapiGetFieldValue(name)

    //make sure it hasn't been set
    if (codetext != nlapiGetFieldValue('custrecord_rulereferencecode'))
    {
      nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_rulereferencecode', codetext );
    }
}

return true
```

}

Comment: I must not fully understand what you're trying to accomplish or how your dynamic list is populated, but I guess if this works for you, then go for it. On an unrelated note, the Field Changed event handler has a void return type, so returning true is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, instead of creating the field as *Free-Text*, you would first create a **Custom List** (*Customization > Lists/Records/Fields > Lists > New*) with all of your dropdown options.

Then you would create your field as a *List/Record* field and select your new Custom List as the "List/Record Type", as depicted below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by giving a source to your drop-down menu. The source field accepts an internal id of a list. This internal id can be an in-built(provided by netSuite) or a custom list created by a user. For Eg: I have a custom list with an internal id '23' which has some list items in it, these can be populated in the drop down menu by the following syntax.

`var start = function(request, response)
{
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Custom Form');
    form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select', 'select a color', '23');//here 23 is the internal id of my list
    respnose.writePage(form);
}`

[image: Here's the form]or you could generate you own field's dynamically using the addSelectOption() function.

`var start = function(request, response)
{
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Custom Form');
    var myselectfield = form.addField('custpage_selectfield', 'select', 'select a color');
    myselectfield.addSelectOption('1', 'Red');//Here 1, 2 and 3 are the id's
    myselectfield.addSelectOption('2', 'Green');//which are returned when the 
    myselectfield.addSelectOption('3', 'Blue');//form is submitted
    respnose.writePage(form);
}`

[image: Here's the Form]